Arithmetic genus of a divisor on surface
Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface and $A$ be a non-trivial effective divisor on $S$ such that $A$ is is both reduced and irreducible. Can we conclude that its arithmetic genus: $\frac{A.(A+K_S)}{2}+1 \geq 0$? ($K_S$ stands for the canonical divisor of $S$)
Is this because one can identify the arithmetic genus with $h^1(A, \mathcal O_A)$ and hence non-negative?

If $A$ is irreducible and non-singular then the arithmetic and the geometric genus ($h^1(A, \mathcal O_A)$) are the same. If $A$ is  singular (and reduced), then you can talk about the geometric genus $g(\tilde A)$ of the normalization $\tilde A$ of $A$, and the arithmetic genus of $A$ is $g(\tilde A)+ \delta$, where $\delta \geq 0$ is a contribution given by the singularities.
You can find more details in the book "Compact Complex Surfaces" of Barth, Hulek, Peters and Van De Ven (see page 84).

Thanks for the answer. As far as I understand, if $A$ is a compact irreducible and reduced curve on a smooth surface $S$, then its arithmetic genus is non-negative. But in my question $A$ was a non-zero effective divisor on $S$. Is the compactness property of $A$ automatic? (or am I missing something obvious here?). Also in the next page of the book there is a mention of the non-negativity statement with irreduciblity replaced by connectedness.

The support of a divisor is closed (it is given by the vanishing of some functions) in a compact surface, so it is also compact.
